# why can't these variables be referenced globally in my p5 functions?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm having trouble understanding how specially defined p5 functions can reference globally defined variables.  Functions like this one -- where a constant supplies the argument for a p5 function locally -- work just fine.

```
function setup() {

}

function draw() {
  ellipse(50, 50, 80, 80);
}
```

But for some reason, I can't get something like this to draw an ellipse:

```
  var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 1024;
  var CANVAS_WIDTH = 768;
  var RADIUS = 150;
  var circleColor = 150;
  var bgColor = 50;

  function setup() {
    backgroundColor = color(bgColor);
    createCanvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);          
  }


  function draw() {
    fill(circleColor);
    ellipse(CANVAS_WIDTH/2, CANVAS_HEIGHT/2, RADIUS*2, RADIUS*2);

  }
```

Apparently the setup function does create a canvas referencing the global variables.  The draw function, however, doesn't seem to reference them.  What am I missing here?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: That code in `draw()` most certainly can reference those variables.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that the `draw()` function can't reference them? What exactly does this code do when you run it? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use variables like that in the `setup()` function.

You have to use the values directly, and you have to assign the variables inside the `setup()` function:

```
  var CANVAS_HEIGHT;
  var CANVAS_WIDTH;
  var RADIUS;
  var circleColor;
  var bgColor;

  function setup() {
    backgroundColor = color(50);
    createCanvas(1024, 768);  

    CANVAS_HEIGHT = 1024;
    CANVAS_WIDTH = 768;
    RADIUS = 150;
    circleColor = 150;
    bgColor = 50;        
  }
```

From the [p5.js faq](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> **Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before setup()?**
>
> In global mode, p5 variable and function names are not available
>   outside setup(), draw(), mousePressed(), etc. (Except in the case
>   where they are placed inside functions that are called by one of these
>   methods.) What this means is that when declaring variables before
>   setup(), you will need to assign them values inside setup() if you
>   wish to use p5 functions. For example:
>
> ```
> var n;
> function setup() {
>   createCanvas(100, 100);
>   n = random(100);
> }
> ```
>
> The explanation for this is a little complicated, but it has to do
>   with the way the library is setup in order to support both global and
>   instance mode. To understand what's happening, let's first look at the
>   order things happen when a page with p5 is loaded (in global mode).
>
> Scripts in are loaded. of HTML page loads (when this is complete, the
>   onload event fires, which then triggers step 3). p5 is started, all
>   functions are added to the global namespace. So the issue is that the
>   scripts are loaded and evaluated before p5 is started, when it's not
>   yet aware of the p5 variables. If we try to call them here, they will
>   cause an error. However, when we use p5 function calls inside setup()
>   and draw() this is ok, because the browser doesn't look inside
>   functions when the scripts are first loaded. This is because the
>   setup() and draw() functions are not called in the user code, they are
>   only defined, so the stuff inside of them isn't run or evaluated yet.
>
> It's not until p5 is started up that the setup() function is actually
>   run (p5 calls it for you), and at this point, the p5 functions exist
>   in the global namespace.

Comment: What about const ? const variables have to be initialized when declared.

Comment: @KirKanos This answer is outdated. It appears that the latest version of p5.js lets you do what OP is attempting, whether you declare your variables with `var`, `let`, or `const`.